# Laravel: Migration error on Deploy

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, laravel-5.5

I want to deploy one of my projects where I used custom blueprint.

On `php artisan migrate` I got the following error:

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
> Class 'Database\CustomBlueprint' not found

I tried `composer dumpautoload` and I got this message:

> Generating optimized autoload files
>
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
>
> You made a reference to a non-existent script @php artisan package:discover

The last row didn't appeared on the local environment.

After `dumpautoload` the `migrate` command made the same result.

Comment: How is your class defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact it really depends where you have `CustomBlueprint` located. In the error there is `Database\CustomBlueprint` but remember `database` directory is not `PSR-4` directory by default.

It's quite possible that's enough to remove `Database` from namespace part from your `CustomBlueprint` and do the same in your migration.

Comment: I got  > [ErrorException] The use statement with non-compound name 'CustomBlueprint' has no effect

Comment: @Feralheart If CustomBlueprint is in global namespace you should completely remove `use CustomBlueprint` in your migration

Comment: I removed it, but I got Class 'CustomBlueprint' not found

Comment: So maybe do like this, put this class into `app` directory and then import it in migration using `use App\CustomBlueprint;`. Of course in `CustomBlueprint.php` add `namespace App;` right after `<?php`